# zsh-autosuggestions: How to install zpty module?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, zsh

I love [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) and found in the README:

> `completion`: Chooses a suggestion based on what tab-completion would
> suggest. (requires `zpty` module)

With a [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=zpty%20zsh&ia=software) I din't find out what `zpty` is and how to install it on macOS. Homebrew prefered.

```
zpty
zsh: command not found: zpty
```

If that matters, I am a `oh-my-zsh` user on latest macOS.

Comment: Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`zpty` is a module that comes bundled with Zsh since version 3.1. The text you quote is just trying to tell you that, if you use a Zsh version older than 3.1, then you cannot use the `completion` strategy in `zsh-autosuggestions`.

If you do use Zsh 3.1 or later, then there's nothing you need to do. `zsh-autosuggestions` takes care itself of [loading `zpty` when it needs it](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/ae315ded4dba10685dbbafbfa2ff3c1aefeb490d/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh#L608).

Answer (score -2):

Apparently [zsh has moved away from zpty](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/pull/338) and suggests the utility [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions) which hopefully would address your use-case. Installing with homebrew does not need zpty as a dependency.

To install:

```
brew install zsh-autosuggestions
```

And after installing, you'll need to edit your .zshrc file to include

```
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

Then reload your .zshrc using:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Hope this helps, and I hope I understood your question.

Comment: The OP is already using `zsh-autosuggestions`. You clearly did not understand their question. Take a moment to read it again.

Comment: "zsh has moved away from zpty": That is complete gibberish. `zpty` is a module included in Zsh. _zsh-autocomplete,_ on the other hand, has eliminated its usage of the `zpty` module, _except_ for the `completion` suggester, which still uses it and which is why that sentence the OP quoted is there in the documentation.